# Finding combinations using recursion in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with finding combinations using recursion
for example

```
a = ['a', 'b','c'], 
b = ['d','e','f']
c = ['g','h','i']
```

input is a,b,c
there are 27 possible combinations

```
combinations = []
if string == "":
    print (combinations)
    return
else:
    for i in string.head():
        recursive_combinations(combinations , string.tail())
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can take a look at what you've done so far. :)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest, idiomatic way would be to use `itertools`, not recursion. Like this:

```
import itertools as it

v1 = ['a', 'b','c']
v2 = ['d','e','f']
v3 = ['g','h','i']

list(it.product(v1, v2, v3))
=> ... the cartesian product of the input lists ...

len(list(it.product(v1, v2, v3)))
=> 27
```